# How to remove all classes with a certain prefix (using Visual Studio Code)?

Tags: css, regex, visual-studio-code

I'm an interaction designer in an Angular based HTML project. I'm trying to create a new HTML template based on one that's made by another team. I use Firebug to capture the existing HTML and modify it in Visual Studio Code.

Along with the HTML that is useful to me, I also get a ton of `ng-` and `cs-` tags, attributes, classes and comments that (I assume) was used to populate the template. I would like to remove them all.

At this point I have been successful at removing the comments, tags and attributes using the following regex:

`(<!--.*(ngIf|ngRepeat|ngInclude).*-->)|(</{0,1}(ng|cs)-.*>)|((ng|cs)-[a-z-]*="[^"]*")`

To break it down:

- Comments: `<!--.*(ngIf|ngRepeat|ngInclude).*-->`
- Tags: `</{0,1}(ng|cs)-.*>`
- Attributes: `(ng|cs)-[a-z-]*="[^"]*"`

But for the time being I'm stuck at classes. I can *find* the things I want to remove: `(class="[^"]*)ng-[-a-z]*([^"]*")` (limitation: removes only one `ng-` class per `class` attribute), but I can't *replace* them using `\1\2`. It seems Visual Studio Code supports regex in the find field, but not in the replace field.

How to proceed?

Comment: What about `$1$2`? Replace field never supports *regex* patterns, but *replacement* patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right, that did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dollar sign to define backreferences in Visual Studio Code.

[image]

Well, I should drop a couple of more comments on your regexes:

- The comment regex will only work with the comments that are single on one line. If there can be two or more on one line, use `<!--(?:(?!-->).)*(ngIf|ngRepeat|ngInclude).*?-->` (note the tempered greedy token `(?:(?!-->).)*`)
- Similar problems may arise with `</{0,1}(ng|cs)-.*>` - use a negated character class `[^<]*?` to prevent any tag overflows - `</?(ng|cs)-[^<]*?>` (note the `<` should be used since `>` is often left unserialized and the `{0,1}` limiting quantifier is in fact equal to `?`)

Note that starting with [VSCode 1.29](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_backreferences-and-lookahead-in-search), you need to [enable `search.usePCRE2` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52150634/3832970) to enable lookaheads in your regex patterns.

Comment: Thanks again. After you provided the `$` solution I discovered that `(class="[^"]*)ng-[a-z]*([^"]*")` is buggy too when there's more than one `ng-` class. I'm new to regex and pushing my luck here :-)

Comment: If you provide a use case, I will try to help.

Comment: I was about to explain, and then I understood that I misunderstood what caused the bug :-)  I should replace [a-z] with [-a-z] to catch items with multiple hyphens such as `ng-isolate-scope`. I still don't get how to catch multiple `ng-` classes inside a single `class` attribute, though.

Comment: If you provide a use case - a sample string with expected output -  I would be able to help.

Comment: OK, so I would like `class="sub-nav ng-scope dropdown-menu ng-hide"` to become just `class="sub-nav dropdown-menu"`. If there are a few extra spaces, that doesn't matter :-)

Comment: Aha, that is impossible with the VSC regex to do that with 1 single regex pass. You can do it with PCRE regexps, or in Notepad++ though. Something like [`(class="|(?!^)\G)((?:(?!ng-)[^"<])*)ng-` and `$1$2` replacement](https://regex101.com/r/kE5hI7/1).

Comment: Holy smokes. I will do multiple, manual passes in VSC then :-D