# Regex in Visual Studio Code: Invalidate match fails with "Unrecognized flag" error

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Edit: As several commenters have pointed out, it should be `^class (?!Migration)[A-Z][a-z]*`. But VS Code complains: `Error parsing regex near "ss (?!Migr' at character offset 9: Unrecognized flag: '!'. (Allowed flags: i, m, s, U, u, x.)`

[`Visual Studio` seems to support negative look aheads (see "Invalidate a match")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2015) . Could not find an answer to the question if VSCode does support it.

---

In VS Code I am trying to find class definitions in a Django project via `Shift+Command+F`. Turned on regex search. Now my search pattern is this:

`^class [A-Z][a-z]*`

So every occurence of "class Abc", where Abc is the class name, will be found.

Now I would like to exclude classes like `class Migration(...)` or `class Command(...)`

I tried to do this with a negative lookahead, like so:

`^class (!?Migration)[A-Z][a-z]*`

But that won't work. VS Code will show me all classes named `class Migration(...)`, so instead of excluding it, it will focus on it.

What am I missing?

Comment: `!?` is not a negative lookahead, maybe you meant `?!`?

Comment: Your regex contains a typo. `^class (?!Migration)[A-Z][a-z]*` should work.

Comment: try `^class\s(?!Migration|Command)[A-Z][0-9a-z]*`

Comment: Yes, I just had a typo. `^class (?!Migration) [A-Z][a-z]*` is the correct form. But VS Code will complain, this time saying: `Error parsing regex near "ss (?!Migr' at character offset 9: Unrecognized flag: '!'. (Allowed flags: i, m, s, U, u, x.)`

Comment: The answer is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41493),  the find in file feature does not support lookarounds as it uses `ripgrep` tool that only supports some kind of POSIX regex syntax.

Comment: Try this: edit your `ripgrep`  settings in the *settings.json* file and set `"search.useRipgrep": false`. Then retry `^class (?!Migration)[A-Z][a-z]*`

Comment: Man, you are a genius! Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Ugur There has been a VScode update, now it has PCRE2 option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

You may use lookarounds freely in your regexps, both  lookaheads and lookbehinds, as a result of moving to *Electron 3.0*. Since lookarounds are supported since Chromium 62 and Node 8.10.0, and Electron 3.0 uses Chromium 66 and Node 10.2.0, they are now supported out-of-the-box.

PCRE2 option is

> Deprecated. PCRE2 will be used automatically when using regex features
>   that are only supported by PCRE2.

Note that starting with VS Code 1.31, even [infinite-width lookbehinds are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868396/3832970).

**Previous answer for legacy versions**

Note that to make your patterns with *lookaheads* work you need to edit your *settings.json* file to set

```
"search.usePCRE2": true
```

See the [v1.29 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_backreferences-and-lookahead-in-search):

> It is also now possible to use backreferences and lookahead assertions
>   in regex searches, by setting `"search.usePCRE2": true`. This configures
>   ripgrep to use the PCRE2 regex engine. While PCRE2 supports many other
>   features, we only support regex expressions that are still valid in
>   JavaScript, because open editors are still searched using the editor's
>   JavaScript-based search.

Also, see [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53375676/3832970) who noticed this option earlier.

Then, your `^class (?!Migration)[A-Z][a-z]*` regex will work.

[image]

Comment: Note that this setting is no longer needed: "Deprecated. PCRE2 will be used automatically when using regex features that are only supported by PCRE2."

Comment: @MarredCheese Great, I modified the answer to reflect the change. It is great that VSCode development is so active.

Answer (score 0):

Use a visual studio code extension called [Reverse Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanishSarwar.reverse-search) for this purpose

Comment: Disclaimer! The author of the above comment is also the author of the extension mentioned above (Reverse Search)