# VSCode internal regex search with negative lookbehind

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, attempting to search for `print(` and `print (` - but only if not followed by `#`

*This is my first time attempting a regex search in VSCode...*

Examples:
`print ('Test One')` - MATCH
`print( 'Test Two')` - MATCH
`#print('Test Fee')` - SKIPPED

I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146620/negative-lookaround-alternative-vscode-ripgrep) that VSCode lacks negative lookbehind.

Ordinarily, in the `^F` (search function) I would use something like (untested):

```
/w*(?<!#)print
```

but I am getting the error that the regex is invalid.

Can anyone suggest a workaround - or have I just fat-fingered the regex ?

Comment: Let's play with the regex101 at first, try `^\s*print\s*\(`, see https://regex101.com/r/cMM5QU/2. Does it do what you expect?

Comment: Note I remove `(?!#)`, as it seems redundant for the pattern above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE NOTE**: Starting with VS Code 1.31, [*infinite-width lookbehinds are supported*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868396/3832970).

However, in the current scenario, you do not have to use a lookbehind based solution, you may use

```
^\s*print\s*\(
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cMM5QU/2)

Note that in case you only want to match text on the same lines, it may be a better idea to replace `\s` with `[ \t]`, or `[^\S\n]`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `print` - a literal substring
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char (must be escaped to match a literal `(`).

**NOTE** that actually VSCode still supports lookaheads, but you need [to enable `search.usePCRE2` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52150634/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

for negative lookaheads you can use this VS code Extension [Reverse Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanishSarwar.reverse-search)