# Visual Studio Code: regex expression starts with but not ends with

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code uses [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) [to search in files](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24626), which [doesn't support look around and backreferences](https://docs.rs/regex/1.0.6/regex/).

I want to build an expression which returns all the phrases which start with a given string and does not end with given string e.g:

Starts with "`http://blah.com`" but not ends with "`.htm`"

Matches:

```
http://blah.com/tmp
```

Doesn’t match:

```
http://blah.com/tmp.htm
blah.com/tmp.htm
```

Comment: I want to search in the whole solution not only in one file

Comment: This question has nothing to do with rust itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your settings (to enable lookahead) :

```
 "search.usePCRE2": true
```

Your regex (using a negative lookahead):

```
blah\.com(?!.*\.htm$)
```

[Edit] Added the `$` if you absolutely want to exclude matches that do not end with the `.htm`,  not just followed somewhere in the string by `.htm`.

From the [v1.29 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_backreferences-and-lookahead-in-search):

> It is also now possible to use backreferences and lookahead assertions
>   in regex searches, by setting "search.usePCRE2": true. This configures
>   ripgrep to use the PCRE2 regex engine. While PCRE2 supports many other
>   features, we only support regex expressions that are still valid in
>   JavaScript, because open editors are still searched using the editor's
>   JavaScript-based search.

[Positive and negative lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

Also note that a previous solution for this has been deprecated:

```
// Deprecated. Consider "search.usePCRE2" for advanced regex feature support.
// This setting is deprecated and now falls back on "search.usePCRE2".

"search.useRipgrep": false
```