# How to use the Negative Lookahead in the search function of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

#### Context:

Handeling PHP 2-3 codes I have to replace short tag "`<?`" by "`<?php`".
In order to find them I wanted to use the VS code find in folder feature to find all occurrence of it.

#### Question:

What is the correct syntax for contains `<?` not followed by `php`?

I've read the visual studio documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and tried in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/i4Dtz8/1).  It seems to be valid in PCRE and ECMA. I must be missing something, because  in Visual Studio Code it doesn't work.

> "Regex parse error".

[image]

#### Regex:

```
<\?(?!php)
```

#### Input:

```
<?php
<?
<?PHP
```

#### Output:

```
<?
```

Comment: Check *User Settings* -> *Features* -> *Search* settings for the `Use PCRE2` option. It must be checked for lookaheads to work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Hoo, great! May you make an answer when you have time. I feel like if it's not a dupe, it will be usefull to others.

Comment: Also that doc you referred to is for Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @revo, I hit google with `"Visual Studio Code"` but he still ignored it. I guess the word "code" is really common on those page.

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149634 , damnezd dupe is easy once you know the name of the feature.